# Connecting PGAdmin to RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, pgadmin

have created a postgre instance in RDS and have created a security group for the VPC with below inbound rules:

```
Type             Protocol      PortRange      Source
Custom TCP Rule   TCP          5432          0.0.0.0/0
All traffic       All          All           0.0.0.0/0
```

I try to connect to the RDS instance using pgAdmin , but get the below error

> could not connect to server: Operation timed out Is the server running
>   on host "xxxxx-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.xxx.xxx.83) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Can you tell me what am i missing?

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. You're better off on ServerFault. That said - at a guess, your VPC configuration isn't forwarding the port. You're only showing us a small slice of your configuration (which with VPC can be quite complex) so it's very hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have specified that you have launched the Postgre RDS instance inside a VPC, you have to make the subnet a Public Subnet by attaching the subnet to an Internet gateway in which the Postgre RDS instance is launched.

Check here for more information about [adding an internet to your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)